# QtWebEngine has no attribute QWebView

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to build a simple interface that can display an HTML file. I migrated to the new `QtWebEngineWidgets` from the old `QtWebWidgets`, and I get:

```
 File "interface.py", line 576, in setupUi
    self.webView = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebView(self.frameDataExploration)
AttributeError: module 'PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets' has no attribute 'QWebView'
```

EDIT:

If I just try to import `QtWebEngineWidgets` separately, I get:

```
>>> from PyQt5 import QtWebEngineWidgets
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /home/user/.conda/envs/mp/bin/../lib/libxcb-dri3.so.0: undefined symbol: xcb_send_request_with_fds
```

Comment: `QtWebEngineWidgets` has `QWebEngineView` instead of 'QWebView'

Comment: Thanks, SOLVED it